# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with an object namely when creating a list of objects it gets an error like in the title.

**Kotlin code**

```
 private fun readNotification() {
        val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications")
            .child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                notificationList.clear()
                for (snapshot : DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                    val notification = snapshot.getValue(NotificationData::class.java)!!
                    notificationList.add(notification)
                }
                notificationList.reverse()
                notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })
    }
```

**Object code**

```
class NotificationData(
    var userId: String = "",
    var text: String = "",
    var postId: String = "",
    var isPost: Boolean = false
) {}
```

**Firebase structure**

[image: Firebase structure]

I know the error is on this line because the object has a boolean variable

```
val notification = snapshot.getValue(NotificationData::class.java)!!
```

I just don't know much how to deal with it now

Answer (score 1):

While I thought the Firebase JSON mapper handled `isBla` format getters, there is only one boolean in your JSON, so it makes sense that the problem comes form there.

You could change the boolean to this:

```
var post: Boolean = false
```

Or add an explicit `@PropertyName` annotation:

```
@PropertyName("post")
var isPost: Boolean = false
```

That said, I think it's a valid expectation for the Firebase mapper to handle boolean `isXyz` properties by default, so would recommend adding a feature request on the Github repo of the SDK.